# Scale image on scroll, sticky to top

Tags: javascript, css, image, scroll, css-transforms

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to the images on this page: https://sameold.com except I only want the images to scale in the y direction.

I'm currently experimenting with using a scale3d(1, (height of image minus y position of image / image height), 1 ) when ever I scroll either up or down.

However the image does not stick to the top of the screen when I scroll.

I'm unsure if I'm having the right approach. I also suspect that the ratio is changing as the height of the getBoundingBoxRect changes.

```
    let section = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    var scrollPos = 0;

    function fracOfHeight(imgH, y) {
    return (imgH + y) / imgH;
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top < scrollPos) {
        section.forEach(function (v) {
        let rect = v.getBoundingClientRect();
        let rectH = rect.height;
        let y = rect.top;
        let frac = fracOfHeight(rectH, y);

        if (y < 0) {
            console.log("down", y, v.style.transform);
            v.style.transform = `scale(${frac <= 1 && frac >= 0 ? frac : 0})`; // largern than 1 or smaller than 0
        } else {
            v.style.transform = `scale(0)`;
        }
        });

        scrollPos = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }

    if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top > scrollPos) {
        section.forEach(function (v) {
        let rect = v.getBoundingClientRect();
        let rectH = rect.height;
        let y = rect.top;
        let frac = fracOfHeight(rectH, y);

        if (y < 0) {
            console.log(
            "down",
            y,
            v.style.transform,
            fracOfHeight(rectH, y),
            rect.height
            );
            v.style.transform = `scale(${frac <= 1 && frac >= 0 ? frac : 0})`;
        } else {
            v.style.transform = `scale(1)`;
        }
        scrollPos = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution after being around GSAP and other experiments.
I ended with a horizontal scroll with sticky on left.

The trick was to listen to the image wrapper and only scale the image inside it. This way the over all container stays the same width and makes it possible to scroll back.

It was way simpler than my initial code. Hope this can be of help to somebody.

```js
let frames = document.querySelectorAll(".image-frame");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  frames.forEach((element) => {
    let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.left < 0) {
      element.querySelector(".image").style.transform = `scale3d(${
        (element.offsetWidth + element.getBoundingClientRect().left) /
        element.offsetWidth
      }, 1, 1)`;
    } else {
      element.querySelector(".image").style.transform = "scale3d(1,1,1)";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,body,div
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

section {
  display: block;
}

.gallery-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.image-frame {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transition-duration: 10ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="gallery-wrapper">
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/950/900?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/1050/450?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/350/100?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/550/745?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/350/100?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
            <div class="image-frame">
                <img src="https://placedog.net/425/745?random" alt="" class="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
</html>
```

Comment: PS: stretching/distorting images this way is something any designer would prohibit you from doing. Have you thought about creating a more 3D effect like flip by (90 deg) with perspective?

Comment: Hi Roko. This effekt is made upon the request from the designer. I also hold a masters degree in visual communication. It sure is a 'none-standart' treatment of images, which is part of the appeal. Personally A less radical effect would be to just scale the frame and crop the image.